# How to make a handlebars helper global (in expressjs)

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, helper

I've got a pretty simple handlebars helper file in `helpers/handlebars.js`:

```
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

hbs.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options) {
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});
```

However, as expected, I can't refer to the `{{#inc}}` helper because I didn't pass it into the `res.render()` function. Is there a way to make all helpers in my file global and "auto-included"?

**edit:**

After trying @1cgonza's awesome answer, I get:

```
hbs.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options) {
      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

When running the app. Here's the `app.js`:

```
var engine      = require('express-handlebars');
                  require('./helpers/handlebars.js')(engine);

app.engine('hbs',           engine({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: 'hbs'}));
app.set('view engine',      'hbs');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try exporting your helpers as a module and then include them in your main app.js

Something like this:

In your `helpers/handlebars.js`

```
function hbsHelpers(hbs) {
  hbs.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options) {
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
  });

  // More helpers...
}

module.exports = hbsHelpers;
```

Then in your app.js (or the file you are using as the index).

```
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
require('./helpers/handlebars')(hbs);
```

Does that work for you?

**EDIT**

Based on the `express-handlebars` [docs](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers), I would change the function in your `helpers/handlebars.js` to something like this:

```
function hbsHelpers(hbs) {
  return hbs.create({
    helpers: { // This was missing
      inc: function(value, options) {
        console.log('reading it');
        return parseInt(value) + 1;
      }

      // More helpers...
    }

  });
}

module.exports = hbsHelpers;
```

Let us know if it works.

**EDIT 2:**

My Bad, wrapping your helpers inside a `helpers:{}` was missing from the `create()` function in the `handelbars.js` file. I've edited my previous answer, see where I placed the comment to know what I am talking about.

As for the `app.js` I think it is a little mixed up, so let me rename a few things to make it clear:

```
// I've changed this from engine to exphbs,
// so there is no confusion with the express engine object that we use later.
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

// Create an instance of the express-handlebars
// If you want to pass any option offered by express-handlebar module
// do it inside the create() in the handlebars.js file
var handlebars  = require('./helpers/handlebars.js')(exphbs);

// The handlebars variable now has an object called engine.
// Use that to define your app.engine
// As said before, you don't need to define any options here.
// Everything is defined in the create() in handlebars.js
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);

// If you are using a different extension, you can change hbs to whatever you are using. 
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: This would definitely work. However, I'm getting the error above - does it look familiar? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the express-handlebars has another way of creating helpers, a bit different from what I am used to, see their [docs](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers)

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative that should work with the handlebars module you are using.

Comment: Almost there :) Now it's saying `Error: Missing helper: "inc"`. Do I need to change anything in `app.js`? I've added some extra lines from my app.js file above.

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by using the `hbs` module for handlebars instead of `express-handlebars`. Seems to have more documentation - and your initial solution worked!

Comment: Ah, ok good. Glad you figured it out. If curious, I've added the solution to the problem with the `express-handlebars` module. At least with the code that is working on my end.

Comment: Can you share the working example using hbs module. I'm facing the same issue, where it reports missing helper.

Comment: Thanks man!! I was just about to pull the last hair off my head! :D

Comment: You really helped me out +1 - it can be a tiny bit more simple even although your last version pretty much nails it.  I left a similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967458/4714516

Comment: Suggestion: rather than bad answer, EDIT, EDIT2 etc: just present the best answer first. Then mention what you changed afterwards if you want to.

Answer (score 17):

you can try:

in helpers/handlebars.js:

```
var register = function(Handlebars) {
    var helpers = {
    inc: function(value, options) {
        return parseInt(value) + 1;
    },
    foo: function(var1, var2) {
        return ....
    }
};

if (Handlebars && typeof Handlebars.registerHelper === "function") {
    for (var prop in helpers) {
        Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
    }
} else {
    return helpers;
}

};

module.exports.register = register;
module.exports.helpers = register(null);
```

in app.js:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var hbsHelpers = exphbs.create({
    helpers: require("./helpers/handlebars.js").helpers,
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    extname: '.hbs'
});

app.engine('.hbs', hbsHelpers.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Comment: Kudos for this helpful answer.  This helped me bridge the gap of passing the handlebars object with the layout back to the engine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You can register both your own customer helpers and the ones from 'handlebars-helpers':

```
const hbshelpers = require('handlebars-helpers');
const multihelpers = hbshelpers();

const helpersDM = {
    hlp: echo => `Echo: ${echo}.`,
    STATIC: `/static`,
};
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    layoutsDir: join(__dirname, 'views', 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'base',
    helpers: {...multihelpers, ...helpersDM},
});
app.engine('.hbs', hbs.engine);
app.setViewEngine('.hbs');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your own helpers using following method,

In your app.js firstly import express-handlebars, express npm module,

```
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

Now configure the exphbs using create method which takes options as objects,

```
const myhbs = exphbs.create({/*config*/ extname:"hbs", helpers:{equal:function(a,b, options){return (a==b)?options.fn(this):options.inverse(this)}}});
app.engine("hbs", myhbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
```

By registering the partials like this one can use it throughout the handlebars as a inbuilt function.