# How to register custom Handlebars helpers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

After a long search I still can't seem to find much information on where to put my custom handlebars helpers. Do I put them in a `<script>` in my webpage's .hbs file? Do I put them in app.js? Do I put them in the page's router?

Here's the helper I'd like to register by the way:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("last", function(array) {
    return array[array.length - 1];
});
```

I'm assuming once I've put that code somewhere I can just use it on any page by using `{{last foo}}`, right?

Comment: It's not relevant where you put those, what's relevant is that you change the `Handlebars` object. That means, whether you put it in `app.js` or `<script>` tag or anywhere else, you need to have access to `Handlebars` object, since you are invoking `registerHelper` method on that object (which injects a helper into that object). After `Handlebars` has been modified, every module referencing that object will have access to the new helper.

Comment: Since you tagged the question with `express-handlebars` why don't you have a look at the docs? https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers it's all there

Comment: Sorry @Molda , I think I may have tagged the wrong thing - I'm using Express and Handlebars and thought that tag was just for that - is Express-Handlebars a separate npm package?

Comment: @Mjh - I'm not sure what you mean by 'has access to the handlebars object' - When trying to put it in my app.js it just said that Handlebars is not defined. Why would I need to define handlebars if I'm already using it? Surely there must be the object definition somewhere in the node_modules folder or something.

Comment: In your `app.js`, have you done `Handlebars = require('express-handlebars');`? Have you imported the `Handlebars` object at all, or did you just think it's globally available?

Comment: @Mjh Thanks, using `Handlebars = require('hbs');` seems to work. I'm new to all of this, thought that as I can use handlebars on all my .hbs files then I could use handlebars on all my .js files :D

Answer (score 5):

For an example, you can see the code below:

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}).engine)
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

var hbs = expressHbs.create({});

// register new function
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('increasePrice', function(price) {
  price+=10;
  return price;
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home', {
    layout: false,
    totalPrice: 300,
  });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
});
```

The code above only an example.

You can see an example on this site: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fog-1n61o

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use `express-handlebars` and register helpers for `.hbs` template you can following my answered.

[How to make a handlebars helper global (in expressjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224612/1289476)